# How to place one highchart on top of another

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I've created two charts.  The first includes a combo chart of box/area charts.  The second is a loop that creates multiple side-by-side polar charts. Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/civilsurfer/kw20pq8n/14/

Please expand the chart so you can see that there's another chart underneath all the polar charts.

My goal is to make this setup as responsive to mobile devices as possible. I want to do this by having the top chart take up the top 80% of the screen height and the second group of charts (polar) to take up the bottom 20% of the screen height.

The major problem I'm having is that I create the first chart's div (and wrapper) at the top of the script in a more straightforward way that I understand...and then create a div via javascript toward the bottom of the jsfiddle JS (line 981). What I want is to include the polar charts in the wrapper div. Instead, right now the polar charts are plotting on top of the box/area charts. Here's likely the problem in that I don't know how to make this div that I create below (for polar charts) to be pushed below the box/area chart.

```
var container2 = document.createElement('div');
container2.style.cssText = 'position: relative; float: left; width: 5%; 
height: 20%; margin-bottom: 0;'
document.body.appendChild(container2);
```

Admittedly, I spent a ton of time creating the charts, but I'm not as good at CSS and integrating all these pieces into a nice layout. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's an image of the general layout/spacing I'm looking for.  I achieved this by giving pixel height to the box/area chart (800px) but on a phone the chart is too big.  That's why I want to use % for height, hoping to keep both the box/area chart and polar charts on the mobile screen as well as on the pc screen.
[image]

Comment: Do you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/k_sav/k2zw1ca8/

Comment: Definitely moving in the right direction.  Thanks.  But I'm wondering why the polar charts at the bottom have such a huge margin? The numbers above and below the polar charts should be pretty flush on top and bottom of the circles.  I'm adding a picture above to show what I'm looking for.  The problem is that I have the spacing/layout good using pixel heights, but that method fails on a mobile device when the chart is 800px high and goes off the screen.  That's why I'm shooting for 80% height.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer.  I ended up adding some CSS for the html and body, and then I appended the second container (polar charts) onto the wrapper.  I put both containers (charts) inside the wrapper and made the wrapper height 100% and the containers 75% and 15%.

http://jsfiddle.net/civilsurfer/mwzkgvq1/2/

CSS:

```
html, body {
height:100%;
}
#wrapper {height: 100%;}
#container {position: relative; height: 75%;}
```